# Can one use Alter Self to assume the form of a Skeleton?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

One of the options of [*alter self*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/alter-self) doesn't specify creature type when transforming appearance.

> ***Change Appearance.*** You transform your appearance. You decide what you look like, including your height, weight, facial features, sound of your voice, hair length, coloration, and distinguishing characteristics, if any. **You can make yourself appear as a member of another race, though none of your statistics change.** You also don't appear as a creature of a different size than you, and your basic shape stays the same, if you're bipedal, you can't use this spell to become quadrupedal, for instance.

Would it be reasonable to assume that assuming the form of a Skeleton is allowed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I Alter Self to look like another creature type?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111573/can-i-alter-self-to-look-like-another-creature-type)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Probably not

Given that a skeleton lacks internal organs, etc, I imagine to alter yourself such that you literally don't have the same basic physiology as a humanoid is beyond the scope of that spell.

[This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/111575/35259) to the related question points out that a zombie is essentially just an undead version of a humanoid (assuming all limbs intact), so doesn't have quite the same problem as a skeleton.

## You could disguise yourself to look like a Skeleton

The spell *[disguise self](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/disguise-self)* would be able to make you look like one though, although you wouldn't stand up to physical examination.

From PHB, pg. 233:

> You make yourself - including you clothing, armor, weapons, and other belongings on your person - look different until the spell ends or until you use your action to dismiss it. You can seem 1 foot shorter or taller and can appear thin, fat, or in between. You can't change your body type, so you must adopt a form that has the same basic arrangement of limbs. **Otherwise, the extent of the illusion is up to you**.

Comment: To further this point, _alter self_ is from the **Transmutation** school of magic, meaning you are truly trying to change your physical structure to remove vital internal organs. Whereas the _disguise self_ is from the **Illusion** school, so it is merely giving the appearance of a skeleton without the need of removing flesh.